# QuickLook in Finder not working

Tags: macos, mac, finder, quicklook

I recently restored my system from Time Machine and now when I press spacebar to do a quick preview on files it shows me nothing. Doesn't matter what type of file it is, it fails. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What about when you hit command+Y does it still show up blank?

Comment: It does show blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bit of research on the matter, You should read this article:

[Snow Leopard 10.6.2: Quick Look is blank after Time Machine restore](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10398867-263.html)

It recommends to reinstall [Mac OS X v10.6.2 Update (Combo)](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/macosx_updates/macosxv1062updatecombo.html)

Also take some time to read this from Apple Support: [blank quicklook](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2231877&start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Thank you! It worked!! I'm not sure why I wasn't able to find that in my Google searching.